# anchor tag with java Script onclick event using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

On this website (https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados/Registro/Index/pt-BR?Length=8) you can download a csv file attached on the following anchor tag by a javascript onclick event:

```
<a href="#divListaArquivos" onclick="carregarDownloadArquivo('11-08-2022')">Negociação Balcão - 11/08/2022</a>
```

I'm trying to write a Python script to download this file, but when I use the **click()** method in the code bellow, nothing happens. I first located the element using the link name with the same results. Now even after locating the element by xpath the file still won't be downloaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get(r"https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados/Registro/Index/pt-BR?Length=8")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/p/a")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pure selenium, but you can use `driver.execute_script()` to trigger the function directly.

Something like this should work:

```
driver.get("https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados/Registro/Index/pt-BR?Length=8")
driver.execute_script("carregarDownloadArquivo('11-08-2022')")
```